# Is Private Google Access also used for instances that have a public IP or where Cloud NAT is used?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

On Google Cloud Platform (GCP): Is Private Google Access also used for instances that have a public IP or where a Cloud NAT is used?

If this is not so, then it probably does not increase latency (because Google will route the traffic internally, even when a public IP for googleapis.com is used) but it likely incurs egress charges.

Comment: Yes, you can. Read this document for specific details, then edit your question when you have a specific question not covered by documentation: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options#service-networking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options#pga) has no effect on instances that have external IP addresses. Instances with external IP addresses can access the internet, according to the internet access requirements[1](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options#pga).

PGA grants a privilege to the VM instances that only have internal IP addresses (no external IP addresses) can use Private Google Access and this way they can reach the external IP addresses of Google APIs and services.

[Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#interaction-pga) never performs NAT for traffic sent to the select external IP addresses for Google APIs and services. Instead, Google Cloud automatically enables Private Google Access for a subnet when you configure a Cloud NAT gateway to apply to that subnet's primary IP address range.

Comment: The question is about `Private Service Access`.

Comment: @JohnHanley Maybe I got it wrong, but this is what I was looking for. I thought Private Google Access and Service Acccess is the same, isn't it? Maybe you can explain the difference in another answer and I will up-vote it, but this is the answer I was looking for. I tried it out just now and it is true, a Cloud NAT gateway enables Private Google Access for a subnet. I am studying for the Professional Network Engineer exam and that is why I care about these nuances.

Comment: @Florian The answer does not match the question. Edit your question so that future reads will get the correct answer to the right question.

Comment: You could review this section of this section[1] of this article to get a better understanding about the differences (connection, supported services and usage)  between Private Google access and Private Service access.[1] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options#private-access-options-for-services